# ODBC connection in AX7 (D365)

Tags: odbc, axapta, sql-server-2017, dynamics-365-operations, dynamics-ax7

I am creating an ODBC connection to Import data from SQL (SSMS) to D365FO.

I have created a Test database and created an ODBC Data Source for it (DSN: *TestDS*, Server: *local*, Default database: *TestDB*).

Running SQL Server ODBC Data Source Test works fine:

> Running connectivity tests...
>
> Attempting connection
>   Connection established
>   Verifying option settings
>   Disconnecting from server
>
> TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!

The Server Browser is running, class runOn server is set.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
public server static void main(Args _args)
{        
    OdbcConnection  con;
    LoginProperty   loginProp;

    loginProp = new LoginProperty();
    loginProp.setDSN("TestDS");

    con = new OdbcConnection(loginProp);
}
```

In the debugging window it throws me the following **error**:

> *"Object 'OdbcConnection' could not be created"*

On the user side I am getting the following **errors**:

> *"ODBC operation failed. Unable to log on to the database."* 
>   *"Unable to retrieve message for retval -1, ODBC call reason code -2, SQLSTATE = []"*

As I know, ODBC for data import hasn't been yet supported in 2016. Is it supported now? I have found the exactly similar standard AX7 code, but I am not able to test if it works in standard.

Anybody had something similar to this and got it solved?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're doing that on a development box? Do you realize that you won't be able to add the data source in Microsoft hosted environments? It doesn't look like viable architecture.
When talking about ODBC support, I suspect you mean Data Management, which isn't related to your code.

Comment: What is your target? Why do you need an ODBC connection? Did you consider using [data entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-entities)?